# giving script selector id the same as the cloned div

Tags: jquery

i am cloning a div with on change events inside .
when i am cloning the div only the scripts in the original div is working.

how can i give the script the same id of the cloned one.

```html
<div class="clone_div" style="margin-top: 16px;text-align: right">
  <div class="card w-75">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button type="button" style="width: 1000px;text-decoration: none;" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm text-right">
                  <span id="std_name">הרשמה</span>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm">
                  <p id="price">ש"ח 000</p>
              </div>
          </div>
      </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <form method="post" id="check_std" novalidate="novalidate">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm ">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?= $p_id ?>" name="p_id" placeholder="מספר ת.ז. *">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm ">
              <input type="date" class="datepicker form-control" value="<?= $b_day ?>" name="b_day" placeholder="תאריך לידה*">
            </div>

          </div>
          <input type="hidden" name="search" value="search">
        </form>

        <div class="row mt-5 mr-1">
          <span class="mr-3">רישום <input type="radio" class="checkbox gn" name="gender" value="boy"> בן <input type="radio" name="gender" class="checkbox gn" value="girl"> בת </span>
          <div class="row col-md-12">
            <div class="col-sm">
              <input type="text" class="form-control  " value="<?= $row['std_name'] ?>" placeholder="שם*">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
              <input type="text" class="form-control " value="" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="שם משפחה*">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row col-md-12 mt-2 ">
            <div class="col-sm">

              <select class="form-control ">
                <option selected disabled>מוסד הלימודים*</option>
                <option value="אהלי תורה">אהלי תורה </option>
                <option value="תלמוד תורה">תלמוד תורה </option>
                <option value="בית רבקה צעירות">בית רבקה צעירות </option>
                <option value="בית רבקה בוגרות">בית רבקה בוגרות </option>
                <option value="גן">גן </option>
                <option value="אחר">אחר </option>

              </select>

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
              <input type="text" class="form-control " value="" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="שם המורה*">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row col-md-12 mt-2 ">
            <div class="col-sm">
              <select class="form-control ">
                <option selected disabled>מידת חולצה*</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="16">16</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
              <select class="form-control">
                <option selected disabled> מסיימת כיתה/גן*</option>
                <option value="גן ראשון">גן ראשון</option>
                <option value="גן תת חובה">גן תת חובה</option>
                <option value="גן חובה">גן חובה</option>
                <option value="כיתה א">כיתה א</option>
                <option value="כיתה ב">כיתה ב</option>
                <option value="כיתה ג">כיתה ג</option>
                <option value="כיתה ג">כיתה ג</option>
                <option value="כיתה ד">כיתה ד</option>
                <option value="כיתה ה">כיתה ה</option>
                <option value="כיתה ו">כיתה ו</option>
                <option value="כיתה ז">כיתה ז</option>
                <option value="כיתה ח">כיתה ח</option>
                <option value="כיתה ט">כיתה ט</option>
                <option value="כיתה י">כיתה י</option>
                <option value="כיתה יא">כיתה יא</option>
                <option value="כיתה יב">כיתה יב</option>

              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row col-md-7 mt-2 ">
            <div class="col-sm">
              <select class="form-control" id="k_type" style="width: 355px">
                <option selected disabled> סוג קייטנה*</option>
                <option value="קייטנת ילדי הגנים" data-price="280">קייטנת ילדי הגנים</option>
                <option value="קעמפ (מסיימות ה- ח)" data-price="350">קעמפ (מסיימות ה- ח)</option>
                <option value="קעמפ (מסיימות א- ד)" data-price="280">קעמפ (מסיימות א- ד)</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row col-md-7 mt-2 " style="width: 313px">
            <div class="col-sm">
              <select class="form-control  boy" style="display: none;width: 355px">
                <option selected disabled> מידת כיפה*</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>

              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row col-md-12 mt-lg-5 ">
            <div class="col-sm">
              <input type="checkbox" value="health"> הצהרת בריאות
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="row col-md-12">
            <div class="col-lg-12 mb-3">
              <h4>פרטי האב</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
              <input type="text" class="form-control  " value="<?= $row['std_f_name'] ?>" placeholder="שם האב*">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
              <input type="text" class="form-control " value="" placeholder="ת.ז. האב*">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row col-md-12 mt-2">

            <div class="col-sm">
              <input type="email" class="form-control  " value="" placeholder="מייל האב*">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
              <input type="text" class="form-control " value="<?= $row['std_f_phone'] ?>" placeholder="נייד האב*">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row col-md-12 mt-3">
            <div class="col-lg-12 mb-3">
              <h4>פרטי האם</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
              <input type="text" class="form-control  " value="<?= $row['std_m_name'] ?>" placeholder="שם האב*">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
              <input type="text" class="form-control " value="" placeholder="ת.ז. האם*">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row col-md-12 mt-2">
            <div class="col-sm">
              <input type="email" class="form-control  " value="" placeholder="מייל האם*">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
              <input type="text" class="form-control " value="<?= $row['std_m_phone'] ?>" placeholder="נייד האם*">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row col-md-12 mt-2">
            <div class="col-sm">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger  btn-sm mr-3 mt-3 remove" id="clone">מחק</button>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    $('.checkbox').on('click', function() {

      if ($(this).val() == 'boy') {
        $('.boy').show();
      } else {
        $('.boy').hide();
      }
    })

    $("#k_type").change(function(e) {
      var name = $('#k_type option:selected').attr('data-price');
      $('#std_name').text(name);
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

This is the script that clone the div

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var cloneCount = 1;

  $("#clone").click(function() {
    cloneCount++
    var clone = $('.clone_div')
      .clone();

    clone.attr('class', 'clone_div' + cloneCount)
    clone.find("#collapseOne").attr("id", "collapseOne" + cloneCount);
    clone.find("#k_type").attr("id", "k_type" + cloneCount);
    clone.find("button").attr("data-target", "#collapseOne" + cloneCount);
    clone.find("span").attr("id", "std_name" + cloneCount);
    clone.find("p").attr("id", "price" + cloneCount);
    clone.find("input:text").val("");
    clone.appendTo(".result");
  });
});
```

This row is giving each of the select tag a new id

```
 clone.find("#k_type").attr("id","k_type" + cloneCount);
```

How can i give this script the same id as the cloned one?

```js
$("#k_type").change(function(e) {
  var name = $('#k_type option:selected').attr('data-price');
  $('#std_name').text(name);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a selector that matches all the IDs that start with `k_type`:

```
$("[id^=k_type]").change(function(e) {
  var name = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-price');
  $('#std_name').text(name);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

[Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

### Edit

Since we are adding the elements dynamically (on clone), we need to attach the event `change` to the parent element and then select the children we want to apply the event handler:

```
// we need to apply this event to an element that exists on the initial page
// .on('change', 'children selector', callback)
$("div.result").on('change', '[id^=k_type]', function(e) {
      // prevent the default behavior
    e.preventDefault();
    // save the <select> element
    var $select = $(this);
    // find the option selected and it's data-price attribute
    var name = $select.find('option:selected').attr('data-price');
    // get the closest parent that has a class starting with clone_div
    var $parent = $select.closest('div[class^=clone_div]');
    // within the parent, find the span that has an id starting with std_name
    var $spanName = $parent.find('span[id^=std_name]');
    // set the text to the span
    $spanName.text(name);
});
```

Comment: do i need to add  $("input:[id^=k_type]") ? when i add your code nothing happens

Comment: You can add the `input` to the selector, however it would be `input[id^=k_type]`, the `:` isn't correct. Nothing happens? Try to debug, either using the developer tools of your browser or adding `console.log()` to see if the event is triggered.

Comment: i cant see any error . still only the script in the original div is working, do i need to clone the script as well?

Comment: Can you provide a snippet with a working copy on your original question?

Comment: this a fiddle of my code u will see a select box with the label of on change when u change it you will see a price changing at the top of the div . its only working in the original one  https://jsfiddle.net/m8u6pxzq/8/